# realloc: Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap

Tags: c

I am working on a program that stores an arbitrarily long list of contacts (names and phone numbers). The entries are stored in an array that is resized each time a new element is added with the `realloc` function. The first contact can be added and displayed normally. However, when I try to add the second contact, the program crashes with the following message:

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
In ntdll!RtlZeroHeap () (C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
```

No breakpoints have been set in my editor. The debugger says the problem is on the line containing the `realloc` statement. How can I fix this issue? I have included the relevant sections of code below.

```
#define STRING_LENGTH 32

typedef struct entry_t {
    char name[STRING_LENGTH];
    char number[STRING_LENGTH];
} Entry;

void *add_entry(Entry*, int);

int main()
{
    int entry_count = 0;
    Entry *entries = calloc(1, sizeof(Entry));
    int choice = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("Options:\n1) Add Entry\n2) Modify Entry\n3) Print Entries\n4) Exit\n\nSelect an option: ");
        scanf(" %d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            entries = add_entry(entries, entry_count++);
            break;
            // ...
        }
    }
}

void *add_entry(Entry *entries, int current_count)
{
    Entry entry;

    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", entry.name);
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", entry.number);
    printf("\n");

    entries[current_count] = entry;
    return realloc(entries, sizeof(Entry) * (current_count + 1));
}
```

Comment: swap the last two lines of code

Comment: I've made an update of my answer giving you a suggestion as to how to improve this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logic problem here. You initially allocate space for one object with
`calloc` then call `add_entry` with the count equals to 0.

Then you add the new entry at index `current_count` which is 0 at this point.
Then you resize the memory with `current_count + 1`, which is also 1. So you are
not resizing the memory at all.

In the next iteration, `entry_count` is 1 and you add a new element at
`entries[1]`. And that's the problem, you are accessing the memory out of
bounds, because you still have space for only **one** object at this time.

Instead of reallocating by `current_count + 1`, you should reallocate by
`current_count + 2`, so that the next iteration has space to put the new
elements at the end of the memory.

```
void *add_entry(Entry *entries, int current_count)
{
    Entry entry;

    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", entry.name);
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", entry.number);
    printf("\n");

    entries[current_count] = entry;
    return realloc(entries, sizeof(Entry) * (current_count + 2));  // <-- +2
}
```

Note that your `current_count` variable is always one step behind the real size of the allocation, that's why you need the `+2`

**edit**

Note also that the more natural way would be to resize first, and then insert
the new object. So I would initialize the memory with `NULL` and do it like
this:

```
int main()
{
    size_t entry_count = 0;
    Entry *entries = NULL, *tmp;
    int choice = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("Options:\n1) Add Entry\n2) Modify Entry\n3) Print Entries\n4) Exit\n\nSelect an option: ");
        scanf(" %d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            tmp = add_entry(entries, &entry_count);
            if(tmp == NULL)
            {
                // error handling
                // entries still point to the old memory
                // could be useful in error handling

                free(entries);
                return 1;
            }

            entries = tmp;
            break;
            // ...
        }
    }
}

void *add_entry(Entry *entries, size_t *current_count)
{
    if(current_count == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Entry entry;

    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", entry.name);
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", entry.number);
    printf("\n");

    if(entries == NULL)
        *current_count = 0;

    Entry *tmp = realloc(entries, (*current_count + 1) * sizeof *entries);

    if(tmp == NULL)
        return NULL;

    entries = tmp;

    entries[(*current_count)++] = entry;

    return entries;
}
```

Note here that the `realloc` **and** the increment of the counting variable
happens in the same function. Only when everything goes OK, you should increase
the counter. Also note that `entries` is initialized with `NULL`, because
`realloc(NULL, size)` is equivalent to `malloc(size)`.